# How to get details of a facebook post from post url using facebook api?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch the details of a facebook post from the post's url. The post will be a public post.

Is it possible to do this via facebook api? If its possible,how?(a link or explanation)

I tried reading through graph api. But I couldn't find the relevant information.

Comment: Atleast provide the reasons for the downvote so that it is of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get any object by fetching it by id and passing encoded url as id. It was working for me as far as now anyway.

simply call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?id=[ENCODED_URL]&access_token=[TOKEN]
```

Also. Post url contains id anyway, so you can just extract the id from url string.

Comment: btw. I don't see any reason why this question should be downvoted

Comment: Thank you for your positive response Daniel!! I've created an app as it was indicated in the "getting started.." section. How do I proceed from here?? I just want to get the data of a particular public post/picture/<anything else>. Do I still have to get the consent of each user?? Or is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what call you are trying to make and what you are trying to fetch?

Comment: You do need the consent of a person, but any page feed can be accessed  without it.

Comment: Basically this is what I'm trying to build - user enters a FB url, my s/w processes the url and using the FB api, the s/w displays the details of the url. For eg, if image url, show description, posted by etc.

Comment: based on what you've said I built until the part where if it is an image or video the s/w fetches the details. But if its a post url from a page, then I get an error `(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher`. How can I fetch the page_id if I have only the post url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117207/discussion-between-daniel-junyszek-and-sidx).